# Login Script for PostGreSQL and PHP not working

Tags: php, postgresql, authentication, session, cookies

I tried this so far:

```
<?php

$error = "";

$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=brittains_db user=brittains password=XXXX" );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM logins";
$result = pg_query($conn, $sql);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    $userName="";
    $password="";
}

else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $userName=trim($_POST["userNameLogin"]);
    $password=trim($_POST["passwordLogin"]);

    if(pg_fetch_result($results, $userName, "userName")==true 
       && pg_fetch_result($results, $password, "userName")==true) {
        setcookie("userIDforDV", $userName, time()+43200);
    }
    else {
        $error = "Your username and or password is incorrect";
    }

}

$userName = $_COOKIE['userIDforDV'];

if(isset($userName) && $userName!="") {
    echo "Welcome " . $userName;
}

echo $error;

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="signupTd">
                User Name:&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="userNameLogin" value="" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="signupTd">
                Password:&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" value="" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="signupTd" colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

That was the idea I came up with... but its probably a really bad idea and it doesn't work... how might I go about this properly? I need really detailed descriptions please.

By the way, my SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE logins(
    userName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    password VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    ageDay INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ageMonth INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ageYear INTEGER NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    createDate DATE
);
```

and my registration form has already been made and is working and I do have users in my database, they just can't login.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you think the problem is?  Otherwise it kind of feels like you're asking someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: Oh this is me self learning and putting stuff together from what I read on website tutorials what not... so its not homework... and my problem is prolly the way im going about doing this. but to be specific... my fetch isn't working. my cookie is causing an error. and im getting undefined variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-result.php 's comments.
edit :
password should be varchar(32) and use md5 passwords (or even better 64 and use sha1).
also I'm not familiar with pgSQL in general, however IMO the correct way would be to use an sql query to check instead of using pg_fetch_result.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE userName = '$userName' AND password = md5('$password');";
$result = pg_query($conn, $query);
if(pg_num_rows($result) != 1) {
    // do error stuff
} else {
    // user logged in
}
```

Comment: god people keep sending me there and its like trying to slowly decypher klingon... I'm very good with JS I can program anything in JS and I go to sites like that even with JS and it confuses the crap outa me.

Comment: Basically that site is what got me as far as I've gotten and I can't get any farther hence why I'm trying to get help here but most appreciate the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see a phenominal login script in action (and thereby learn from it) Check out jpmaster77's core: http://evolt.org/node/60384 It has a strong class based infrastructure and takes full advantage of your object-oriented background.  It works out of the box & is free.

glhf